# ArangoDB: Running production environments on Windows is not supported

Tags: windows, arangodb

What does it mean? "Running production environments on Windows is not supported".
I'm supposed to run an instance of ArangoDB on Windows Server 2012.
Is it not supported?

Comment: That would appear to be the meaning of that sentence in plain English, yes. Note that "not supported" does not mean "will not work".

Comment: So what is the point of having buildable source code of the server software available?  Why is there even a distribution of the server product available?  Just to test on before using the Dockerized, product?